# Blendshapes wont create!

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to create i blend shape but after i finish making one, the vertices never reset and don't even move after i edited them. Please help! https://gyazo.com/2328df14475881eb5ed40e57ad29846e
I tried creating it at 0 that still didn't make any difference, it's not the first time i create blend shapes on this same mesh and it worked fine before, now i'm completely confused as to what happened.
P.S. the vertices screw up the mesh as well when moving the blendshape value or deleting the blendshape, mesh looks deformed.

Comment: you can press L to select the whole mesh, you don't need to switch to the material tab and press Select, but that doesn't anwser  ;)  maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The file you're working on, you created it with another version of Blender or are you using the same version you created the file with?

Comment: i never change my blender version from 2.79 it was always on it

Comment: Try again or use another way to share file (someone will upload it :)

Comment: I can't download with the site you're using (dropmefile), I don't know why

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/tt9hjbg9d3dyi48/tail+(1).blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Automatically merge vertices at the same location"* is on...

[image]

So, turn it off to solve the issue.

Comment: OMG u saved me! thank u so much!